# How to initialise a variable in Javascript to INFINITE value?

Tags: javascript

How can I initialise a variable in javascript to the biggest possible number? I am looking for an equivalent of:

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` --> Java

`INT_MAX` --> C

`int.MaxValue` --> C#

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)

Comment: [Infinity In JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)

Comment: I would like to remark that the title of your question does not match your actual question. That's somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new added **ECMAScript** feature [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
```

Comment: Yes, that's a new feature. We have finished ECMAScript 2020 and actual ESNext, which is the concept of ES2021. And in the ES2021, we have this constant which is 2^53-1.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i =  Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
console.log("infinity:", i)
var max =  Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
console.log("max:", max)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) `Number.MAX_VALUE` returns the biggest number possible in Javascript smaller than infinity.

Since it is larger than the maximum safe integer (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` = 2 ^ 53 - 1 vs 2 ^ 1024 for `Number.MAX_VALUE`), it is best represented using the `BigInt` object which appends `n` to the end of the value. i.e.:

```js
const maxSafeValue = BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE);
// returns 17976...n
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type less:

```
var i = 1/0
console.log(i)  // Shows 'Infinity'
```